# Add new picklist values to all Record Types that use this Global Value Set

Tags: record-type, tooling-api, httprequest, global-picklist

I'v been used tooling API for update Global value set.
but now the new picklist values i'v added doesn't display at the picklist field.
I'v notice to the check box when adding new values to global value set:
[image]

How can I add the new picklist values to all Record Types that use this Global Value Set using tooling API?

Is there a way to update all new values to all Record Types by default?

Answer (score 2):

At the metadata level, you have to deploy all the values to the record types (found in the Object metadata). There's no "flag" in the API to do this automatically, so you just need to deploy the changes to the record types as well. If you're using a Scratch Org, you may find it easier to create the new picklist value in the UI, then force:source:pull to get all the changes, which should include the record types as well.

Comment: How I  deploy the changes to the record types ? Can I do this to all  record types together or need to do this to every record separately?

Comment: @Shoval you can deploy all the record types at once, even across multiple objects.